# React and <template>

Tags: reactjs, templates

Trying to figure out how template stuff works with React ...

I have class:

```
 class MyClass extends HTMLElement {

   constructor() {
    super();
    const template = document.querySelector('template');
    const templateContent = template.content;
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    shadow.appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
   } 
   ...........
   window.customElements.define('player', MyClast);
```

and I have template to be called

```
  <template>...</template>
```

I suppose this template should be stored in separate file ... But where exactly? Should it be .html file ? Should I import it?

Can't find anything usefull on this simple question.

Comment: Why do you want to use it with react?

Comment: If you do decide to store it as a separate HTML file  and want to import it, you can use `fetch` for the same or just simply use the `import` statement.